# What is the reason behind this Eclipse behavior due to changing an Environment Variable?

Tags: java, c++, eclipse

I have two versions of Eclipse that I use (Indigo for C++ and Helios for Java). I've used both for years without problems. Last week I needed to view Java Bytecode, so in my Environment Variables I added "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_26\bin;" to the Path variable (this let me use javap 'class' -c to view bytecode in a command prompt).

I continued to use Helios just fine. Today I tried booting up Indigo to work on some C++ code, but I got the "Failed to load JNI shared library etc." error for it, causing it to force close. Eventually I tried removing that path I placed in environment variables, and Indigo boots up correctly again.

Any idea why this happened? I don't fully understand paths, but I don't see why adding the path I did would cause my other Eclipse to break. I don't really need javap anymore so I removed the path, but I'm still curious as to why this happened.

Thanks for any insight!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the change to the path Eclipse was probably trying to load 32 bit Eclipse with a 64 bit Java (or the other way round), they both have to be 32 bit or 64 bit.

Comment: But why does adding the path in Environment Variables break my Indigo Eclipse when previously not having a path of any kind let me run Indigo just fine? Did adding the path "overwrite" the startup of Indigo in a way, so that all my programs using java used the path instead of the path they used to use?

Comment: It probably found a different Java in the path from the one it normally uses. Look in 'Help > About Eclipse > Installation Details button > Configuration tab' to see what the Java being used.